# How to do a AJAX click post on every PHP foreach result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I have read multiple sorts of answers but none works.
what i try to do is to make every result from a PHP foreach loop clickable and then send that data with AJAX to a other PHP file, the problem now is that whatever i do, only the last foreach result always get send and not the result that i clicked on? (without Database)

the loop exist in a function functions.php:

```
public function getForeachResult ()
{
    $response = $this->GetObject($parameters);

        include 'template.php';
}
```

the template that handles the result template.php:

```
<?php
foreach ($response->Result->List as $key =>$value) {

    ?><table id="mytable"><tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>firstname</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($value as $key=>$value) {?>

            <tr class="myrow">
            <td><?php echo $value->ID; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value->Time)); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->FullName; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value->LastName; ?></td>
            </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </table><br />

<?php } ?>
```

In template.php the AJAX script is called at the bottom:

```
<script>
$('.myrow').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "post.php",
        data: { action: 'goTo', value: <?php echo $value->ID ?>}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $('.Data').html(msg);
    });
});
```

In post.php where the dat is send i only get the last result of the foreach loop
post.php:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'goTo') {
    var_dump ($_POST);
}
```

so how can i make sure AJAX sends the data that i clicked on?

Comment: data: { action: 'goTo', value: $(this).find(td:first).text().trim()}

Comment: the problem here is that you have no distinct identifier of what row was clicked. that is why you are only able to fetch the last row always. you should instead add a clickable button to your table that will be unique

Comment: Your reusing the variables `$key` and `$value` in the 2nd loop, which could cause unexpected results. Rename the variables in the 2nd loop.

Comment: You are only getting the last value, because that is the only thing you are outputting - your JS code is _outside_ of your foreach loop. And no, you don’t want to put it inside, that would not make sense either - you would have to define a separate click handler for each row. Just read the data from the HTML code when the click happens, as @JYoThI suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
`<td class="id"><?php echo $value->ID; ?></td>
<script>
 $('.myrow').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).find('.id').text();
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "post.php",
    data: { action: 'goTo', value: $(this).find(td:first).text().trim()}
   }).done(function( msg ) {
    $('.Data').html(msg);
  });
});`
```

I think your php expression in the data field just hold the last id because you looped in your html but in your ajaxcall your are already in the end of the loop.

Edit: took the comment

Comment: Thank you, with a class this works fine and it's clear

Answer (score 0):

You need use traverse to  find the each row value dynamically on click  like this

```
var clicked_row_id = $(this).find('td:first').text().trim();
```

Data should be send like this

```
data: { action: 'goTo', value: clicked_row_id }
```

**Update 1 :**

```
$('.myrow').click(function() {

    var clicked_row_id = $(this).find('td:first').text().trim();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "post.php",
        data: { action: 'goTo', value:clicked_row_id }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $('.Data').html(msg);
    });
});
```

> At the end of foreach loop you will only have last iteration value only in `$value->ID;` . so when you echo it in js. so it will echo only last value .

Answer (score 0):

So, to explain the why, i think you mess up a little things in your head and that causes a confusion. Your PHP file does send nothing in Ajax to another PHP file. Your PHP file builds an HTML page, and the Javascript in this page sends data in Ajax.

Keep that in mind, that in PHP you build a future JS code that is executed later. If dynamic variables have to be retreived during the Ajax call or for its data to send, it will be JS that will do it, not PHP.

So like others answers suggest, you have to retreive the id in JS, not PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the explain, my JS is not the best, but surely will keep this in mind in the future

Answer (score 0):

Only you need to do is get the clicked id just like this

```
    $('.myrow').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).children("td.first").text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "post.php",
        data: { action: 'goTo', value: id}
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $('.Data').html(msg);
    });
```

It will work fine no need to change your table html